# Python tkinter moving buttons to 1 window instead of 2

Tags: python, python-2.7, user-interface, tkinter

My question is about Python 2.7 tkinter. The difficulty lies in getting all the buttons in one window, right now it opens 2 windows, one window with the size I defined, and one with all the button without a defined size.

```
    from Tkinter import *

master = Tk()

class Calculator:
    def __init__(self,master):
        self.var = IntVar()
        frame = Frame(master)
        frame.grid()
        f2 = Frame(master,width=500,height=500)
        f2.grid(row=0,column=1)


def callback():
    print("Hello World")

b = Button(master, text="Calc", command=callback)
b.grid()


e = Entry(master, width=10)
e.grid()

e.focus_set()

b1 = Button(master, text = "Ok", width=10, command = callback)
b1.grid(row=20, column=30)


top = Tk()
app = Calculator(top)
mainloop()
```

Comment: You cannot call `Tk()` twice in the same program.  If you actually want multiple windows, you have to use `Toplevel()` instead for all of them but the first.

Comment: You're creating two windows. Why don't you simply not create the second window?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tkinter requires exactly one instance of `Tk()` to start the tkinter app and one instance of `mainloop()` to manage the update loop.

If you call on `Tk()` more than once you will run into the issue of having multiple windows and things not working as you want.

If you do happen to need a 2nd or more windows then you will need to use `Toplevel()` to create them.

If you delete:

```
top = Tk()
```

and change:

```
app = Calculator(top)
```

to:

```
app = Calculator(master)
```

You will have everything in one window as intended.

Comment: thanks I wish I had better reputation so I could upvote :-D

Comment: Glad to help. Keep in mind your issue is relatively common and has been asked in various forms. Next time you should try to search stack overflow for similar issues. `Tkinter is opening 2 windows. I dont know why` for example. Is a very common question.